# #define an array value with index

Tags: c++, arrays

For Legacy reasons I need to maintain the old array structure(s), however the compiler tells me that there is a problem with my 'expression syntax'.

Here's what I have:

```
#define Array[GlobalIndexVariable]    Get(GlobalIndexVariable)->SubType;
```

`Get` returns a valid pointer to a struct, which contains `SubType`

Now I imagined this to take every occasion of `Array[GlobalIndexVariable]` and simply convert it to the function call, but apparently I was mistaken.

I don't even really know what to search for in this context, so a little help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Edit:
Since it was asked, here is one of the lines that throw the error:

```
LocalVariable = Array[GlobalIndexVariable];
```

I wish to stress, that I'm not looking to make this into a `macro`, but much rather just want to replace `Array[GlobalIndexVariable];` with `Get(GlobalIndexVariable)`, so as soon as anything other than `GlobalIndexVariable` is used, the replacement would fail and throw a different error.

Edit:

Just to make absolutely sure that I am understood:

Right now I have 4 long arrays of type `int`. I want to stuff these into a struct to both mark that they belong together (they describe different aspects of the same thing) however I need a bulk solution for the previous code fragments (a few thousand occurrences).

Old:

```
int Index = 2;
int Array1[ANZ] = { 0, 1, 2 };
int Array2[ANZ] = { 0, 1, 2 };
int Array3[ANZ] = { 0, 1, 2 };
int Array4[ANZ] = { 0, 1, 2 };
if(Array1[Index] == 2) //doSomething
```

New:

```
struct {
    int Type, Conf, Foo, Bar;
};
if(Array1[Index] == 2) //doSomething
```

Without touching `Array1[Index] == 2`, is it possible to use a define or something else to get the exact same behavior as before for the old code?

Comment: That's not valid macro syntax.

Comment: @Mat C++, actually. I added C because it's basically a C problem. Besides, I don't think overloading int is the best idea right here.

Comment: @molbdnilo It's not supposed to be a 'macro', but much rather a simple replacement. Technically I want the compiler to run into the exact text I have on the right side, instead of a calculated value.

Comment: Overloading `int` isn't possible whatever that would mean. But you probably have other options. It would be best if you provided a "complete" minimal example of what you're trying to achieve, with the types of the different things involved. Someone can probably give you a nice (or at least workable) solution then.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium That's a macro. C preprocessor macros are simple replacements, but not of arbitrary text. They're not a good substitute for search-and-replace or `sed`. (`#define TRUE 1` is also a macro.)

Comment: So `Array` and ´GlobalIndexVariable` are never used except in this combination?

Comment: @MOehm Very rarely and if so, I'll amend them manually. I'm looking for a bulk solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a custom type, you may do

```
struct MyType
{
    int& operator[](int index) const { return Get(GlobalIndexVariable)->SubType; }
};

#define Array MyType{}
```

And then

```
Array[GlobalIndexVariable]
```

will be replaced by

```
MyType{}[GlobalIndexVariable]
```

which will calls

```
Get(GlobalIndexVariable)->SubType;
```

Comment: That...appears to be completely feasible. I'm going to try it right away. A bit verbose for my taste, but if I can't have the subscript operator as part of the identifier this is going to be best I can get.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It appears to work. However there is one correction I need to make: It's not `#define Array MyType{}`, but `#define Array MyType()`. Thank you very much again.

Comment: `MyType{}` is correct since C++11, in your are in C++03, indeed, use `MyType()`.

Comment: Heh...I didn't know that. Yes, I'm (stuck) on C++03. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `#define`

```
#define Array[GlobalIndexVariable]    Get(GlobalIndexVariable)->SubType;
```

The [] isn't a valid syntax for macro calls. If you're doing C++ you can write an operator[] for your array type. If you're in C your in a bit of a bind. You'll probably have to replace everything with round brackets rather than square ones.

Comment: I am aware that it isn't a macro. It's not supposed to be either, but much rather a simple replacement. So, when the preprocessor is done, it is supposed to run into the exact text on the right side. No variable expansion or the likes.

Comment: Yes, but the macro preprocessor doesn't work like that. It'll replace Array with the [ and everything afterwards.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I want. For it to take the expression and convert it to what I have on the right side. Or wait, did you mean that it would make `Array[GlobalIndexVariable]` into `[GlobalIndexVariable]` or something?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Currently it replaces all the occurences of `Array` with `[GlobalIndexVariable]    Get(GlobalIndexVariable)->SubType;`, and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf If we could get rid of the first `GlobalIndexVariable`, it'd be exactly what I want.

Comment: *Sigh*...fine, I'll yield. I guess I was being too ambitious with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd perform a substitution, writing something like

```
#ifdef USE_OLD_SYNTAX
# define GET_ARRAY_VALUE(globalIndex) Array[globalIndex]
#else
# define GET_ARRAY_VALUE(globalIndex) Get(globalIndex)->SubType;
#endif
```

Then use `GET_ARRAY_VALUE` in your code and check with `USE_OLD_SINTAX` which definition you want to use by find-and-replace your previous code.

But maybe it can be more simple a find-and-replace inside your code without macro at all.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didn't require me to touch the old code if possible. If it had been a function call to begin with this would be the solution, that's for sure.

Comment: If you change a structure, you must obviously change the code where needed. And changing the code is more clean than finding a workaround that use old syntax with new structure that affect code readibility.

Comment: I begin to fear that you might be right about that.